# Make Identity core options configurable with database

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I am new to aspnet core. we are using identity core 2.1. Now made a page from where admin can set the different configuration like idle-time lockout-time password-retries. Those settings are being  saved into the database table. Now I want that my identity option will set from those values. I made a repository to get setting from database. but I am unable to call that repository function from startup.cs.

Can some please guide me? and Also tell me the best way to make identity options configurable from database.

I have made a service

```
public class SecuritySettingService : ISecuritySettingService
{
    private readonly ISecuritySettingRepository _securitySettingRepository;
    public SecuritySettingService(ISecuritySettingRepository securitySettingRepository)
    {
        _securitySettingRepository = securitySettingRepository;
    }
    public SecuritySetting GetSecuritySetting()
    {
       return  _securitySettingRepository.GetSecuritySetting();
    }
}
```

A repository to connect to database

```
public class SecuritySettingRepository : ISecuritySettingRepository
{
    private readonly IDbRepository _dapperWrapper;
    public SecuritySettingRepository(IDbRepository dapperWrapper)
    {
        _dapperWrapper = dapperWrapper;
    }
    public SecuritySetting GetSecuritySetting()
    {
        var response = _dapperWrapper.QuerySingleOrDefault<SecuritySetting>("security_setting_get", null, CommandType.StoredProcedure);

        return response;
    }
}
```

Made identity config class to clean up startup.cs

public static class IdentityConfig
    {
        public static void ConfigureIdentity(IServiceCollection services, ISecuritySettingService securitySettingService)
        {

```
        var securitySetting = securitySettingService.GetSecuritySetting();
        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>(options => {
            options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
            options.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
            options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = true;
            options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
            options.Password.RequireLowercase = true;


        }).AddUserManager<CustomUserManager>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();





        services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
        {
            // Default User settings.
            options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters =
                    "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-._@+";
            options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;


        });

        services.Configure<DataProtectionTokenProviderOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.TokenLifespan = TimeSpan.FromDays(30);
        });

        services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
        {
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(1);
            options.LoginPath = "/login";
            options.LogoutPath = "/logout";
            options.Cookie = new CookieBuilder
            {
                IsEssential = true // required for auth to work without explicit user consent; adjust to suit your privacy policy
            };
        });

    }
}
```

startup.cs file is like

```
public class Startup
{
    public ISecuritySettingService _securitySettingService;
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, ISecuritySettingService securitySettingService)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
        _securitySettingService = securitySettingService;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {



        IdentityConfig.ConfigureIdentity(services, _securitySettingService);


        services.AddOptions();
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
        services.AddAntiforgery(o => o.HeaderName = "XSRF-TOKEN");

        services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {

    }
}
```

in startup.cs when  I call  IdentityConfig.ConfigureIdentity(services, _securitySettingService); the object _securitySettingService is not present so my code throws exception invalid operation

Comment: what is the error? what did you try so far? please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your current error, you did you register `ISecuritySettingService` and used it in `Startup`. For referencing `ISecuritySettingService`, you need to register it first.

For `services.Configure<IdentityOptions>`, it will not change automatically while changing the database. You need to update `IdentityOptions` by yourself.

Follow Steps below and modify it as needed.

1. `ISecuritySettingRepository`

   ```
   public interface ISecuritySettingRepository
   {
       LockoutOption GetSecuritySetting();
       LockoutOption UpdateSecuritySetting(LockoutOption lockoutOption);
   }
   ```
2. `SecuritySettingRepository`

   ```
   public class SecuritySettingRepository : ISecuritySettingRepository
   {
       private readonly DbConnection _dapperWrapper;
       private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

       public SecuritySettingRepository(DbConnection dapperWrapper
           , IConfiguration configuration)
       {
           _dapperWrapper = dapperWrapper;
           _configuration = configuration;
       }
       public LockoutOption GetSecuritySetting()
       {
           using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")))
           {
               string sQuery = "SELECT top 1 * From LockoutOption Where Id = 1";
               var response = connection.QueryFirstOrDefault<LockoutOption>(sQuery);
               return response;
           }
       }

       public LockoutOption UpdateSecuritySetting(LockoutOption lockoutOption)
       {
           using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")))
           {
               string sQuery = $"Update LockoutOption Set MaxFailedAccessAttempts = {lockoutOption.MaxFailedAccessAttempts} Where Id = {lockoutOption.Id}";
               var result = connection.Execute(sQuery);
               string sQuery1 = "SELECT top 1 * From LockoutOption Where Id = 1";
               var response = connection.QueryFirstOrDefault<LockoutOption>(sQuery1);

               return response;
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. `ISecuritySettingService`

   ```
   public interface ISecuritySettingService
   {
       LockoutOption GetSecuritySetting();
       LockoutOption UpdateSecuritySetting(LockoutOption lockoutOption);
   }
   ```
4. `SecuritySettingService`

   ```
   public class SecuritySettingService : ISecuritySettingService
   {
       private readonly ISecuritySettingRepository _securitySettingRepository;
       private readonly IdentityOptions _identityOptions;

       public SecuritySettingService(ISecuritySettingRepository securitySettingRepository
           , IOptions<IdentityOptions> identityOptions)
       {
           _securitySettingRepository = securitySettingRepository;
           _identityOptions = identityOptions.Value;
       }
       public LockoutOption GetSecuritySetting()
       {
           return _securitySettingRepository.GetSecuritySetting();
       }

       public LockoutOption UpdateSecuritySetting(LockoutOption lockoutOption)
       {
           var option = _securitySettingRepository.UpdateSecuritySetting(lockoutOption);
           //update identity options
           _identityOptions.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = option.MaxFailedAccessAttempts;
           return option;
       }
   }
   ```
5. Register in `Startup`

   ```
   public class Startup
   {
       public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
       {
           Configuration = configuration;
       }

       public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

       // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
       public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
       {
           services.AddTransient<DbConnection>(serviceProvider => new DbConnection(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
           services.AddMvc();
           // your rest configure services

           services.AddTransient<ISecuritySettingService, SecuritySettingService>();
           services.AddTransient<ISecuritySettingRepository, SecuritySettingRepository>();
           var _ecuritySettingService = services.BuildServiceProvider().GetRequiredService<ISecuritySettingService>();
           services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
           {
               options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = _ecuritySettingService.GetSecuritySetting()?.MaxFailedAccessAttempts ?? 3;
           });
       }

       // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
       public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
       {
           //your configure
       }
   }
   ```
6. Useage

   ```
   namespace DapperPro.Controllers
   {
       public class LockoutOptionsController : Controller
       {
           private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
           private readonly IdentityOptions _identityOptions;
           private readonly ISecuritySettingService _securitySettingService;
           public LockoutOptionsController(ApplicationDbContext context
               , IOptions<IdentityOptions> identityOptions
               , ISecuritySettingService securitySettingService)
           {
               _context = context;
               _identityOptions = identityOptions.Value;
               _securitySettingService = securitySettingService;
           }        

           // POST: LockoutOptions/Edit/5
           // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
           // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
           [HttpPost]
           [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
           public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, [Bind("Id,AllowedForNewUsers,MaxFailedAccessAttempts,DefaultLockoutTimeSpan")] LockoutOption lockoutOption)
           {
               _securitySettingService.UpdateSecuritySetting(lockoutOption);

               return View(lockoutOption);
           }        
       }
   }
   ```